# Django ORA-03113 error using multithreading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, oracle

I have a system that basically starts threads from the main processes, several parameters are passed to those threads, I need to access the DataBase to fetch those parameters.

So the code basically is:

```
from procs import Processor
from multiprocessing import Pool

active = True
while active:
    parameters = Parameters.objects.all()

    processor = Processor()

    django.db.connections.close_all()

    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    pool.starmap(processor.proces, parameters)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()

    active = int(Parameters.objects.get(dsc='is_active').value)
```

When I try to get the 'is_active' active parameter after the pools ends the processing I get the ORA-03113 error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel on connection closing
```

Comment: What version of django and cx_Oracle were you running?

Comment: Currently its the 6.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

It looked like the problem was:

```
django.db.connections.close_all()
```

Usually Django should be able to reopen the connections when needed, but I don't know why that wasn't happening, so I forced the reconnection by adding the following code line:

```
django.db.connections['default'].connect()
```

The final code is:

```
from procs import Processor
from multiprocessing import Pool

active = True
while active:
    parameters = Parameters.objects.all()

    processor = Processor()

    django.db.connections.close_all()

    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    pool.starmap(processor.proces, parameters)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()

    django.db.connections['default'].connect()
    active = int(Parameters.objects.get(dsc='is_active').value)
```